# Can I sort query results by using a method instead of an attribute?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Example:

```java
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @NonNull
    private String userName;

    private OtherObject otherObject;

    @JsonIgnore
    public String getInfoBasedOnOtherObject() {
        if (userName == null) {
            return "Option 1";
        }
        if (otherObject.someField == null) {
            return otherObject.getSomeOtherField();
        } else {
            return "Option 3";
        }
    }
```

When getting all users in a Page with a JpaRepository by using `findAll(Sort sort);`, is it possible to sort by the `getInfoBasedOnOtherObject` method instead of an attribute?